# Is there any way to auto-reconnect with a specific PPTP connection on Android?

Tags: networking, wi-fi, vpn

Every time my phone switches between networks (e.g. 4G to Wi-Fi) the established PPTP connection drops.

I know there is a feature called Always-on VPN, but that seems to only apply to L2TP or IPSec connections.  When I select that option it says "Select a VPN profile to always stay connected.  Network traffic will only be allowed when connected to this VPN."  However, the only option listed is "None", even though you can clearly see a PPTP config behind this window.

I am attempting to use proXPN service in particular but suspect this problem is generalized to PPTP sessions.  For what it's worth the phone is running Android 4.3 and has not been rooted.

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this feature might be hard to have since PPTP doesnt have an active connection. This means the OS or the app has to take up bandwidth and battery power to long pull (keep pinging) the PPTP server...